# Conversion of Unicode >> U+9FFF to form URLs

Tags: objective-c

Trying to convert strings that contain an escaped unicode (ex: \u3400) in the range of U+20000 to U+2B81F to form URLs, but it's not working. The range U+3400 to U+9FFF works just fine.

```
NSString *string1 = @"\u9FFF";
string1 = [string1 stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/Search?search=%@", string1]];
NSLog(@"url1: %@", url1);
```

**OUTPUT**: url1: http://en.wikipedia.org/Search?search=%E9%BF%BF

```
NSString *string2 = @"\u20000";
string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/Search?search=%@", string2]];
NSLog(@"url2: %@", url2);
```

**OUTPUT**: url2: (null)

Basically, what I want is to convert a list of escaped unicodes (\u3400 to \u2B81F) to URLs (or even NSStrings). If there is another way to achieve this by other string conversion means, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're trying to de-escape a Unicode char, when NSString is already UTF-8 encoded:

EDIT: I've got it!  It sure doesn't NSLog() at all, but it ain't (null), and that's all that matters.

```
const char * str = "\0xF0\0xA0\0x80\0x80";
NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/Search?search=%@", string2]];
NSLog(@"url2: %@", string2);
```

Comment: You're right CodaFi, de-escaping was indeed useless. I ran your lines,  but I'm still getting a nil string for `\u20000` (`\u9FFF` is OK.)

Comment: Maybe because \u2000 is a space.

Comment: According to this [link](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=U%2B20000), \u20000 is a Chinese character. It is the same behavior throughout the whole range U+20000 through U+2B81F, which corresponds to CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B,C,D and CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement (2F800–2FA1F).

Comment: Found it!  That char is sure hard to track down.  It is escaped in C using `\uD840\uDC00`, not `\u20000`;

Comment: CodoFi, thanks. The whole point of this was to convert \u20000 (or 00020000, wich I think it's UTF-32; from [unihan.org](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=U%2B20000)) into F0 A0 80 80 (UTF-8). If I can do that, I should be able to build URLs like http://en.wikipedia.org/Search?search=%F0%A0%80%80 for \uD840\uDC00 or F0 A0 80 80. Do you know how to achieve that? I'm quite confused with this now...

Comment: How did you go from \u20000 to \uD840\uDC00 and \0xF0\0xA0\0x80\0x80 (F0 A0 80 80)?

Comment: Well, initially, \u20000 wouldn't render because it's out of the usual #FFFF range, so I [looked it up](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20000/index.htm) and found the C-string equivalent.  Unfortunately, Xcode said it was invalid, so I escaped a byte sequence.  That should work great.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi. I'll mark your answer as accepted as it's help me quite a lot. I now need to figure out how to convert UTF-32 (hex) to UTF-8 (hex).